# Compose URL from its parts

Tags: jroute

Is there a method to create URL from different parameters?

For example, from:

```
id=1
option=view
task=delete
```

to:

```
index.php?id=1&option=view&task=delete
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use php method [http_build_query](http://php.net/http_build_query) to generate url encoded query string.

Club all the different parameters in an array and pass it to this method.

Like

```
$base_url = 'index.php?';
$parameter = array('id'=>'1',
              'option'=>'view',
              'task'=>'delete');

$base_url .= http_build_query($parameter);
```